# if google play services blocked in some countries does google services api will work on android devices

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-play-developer-api, android-googleapiclient

if google play services blocked in some countries does google services api will work on android devices

in cases that the device already have play service already installed on it
and if the google play service not installed

Comment: if google app service is not working, then google services are not working either. the app used the apis.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny if google play service is installed but it is blocked from working in some countries and there is app use GoogleApiClient to get location does it will work

Comment: logically, it shoudn't!